# How to access shell from model?

Tags: cakephp-3.0

How can the bake shell be called from a controller in CakePHP 3?

```
\Cake\Console\ShellDispatcher::run(array(__FILE__, 'bake'));
```

leads to Error: `Shell class for "Bake" could not be found.` When adding

```
use Bake\Shell;
```

at the top it leads to `Shell class for "Bake" could not be found.` :-(

Comment: Why would you need a shell inside the model? This makes no sense from an architectural point of view. Pass the data you get in the shell to a model layer class (it doesn't has to be a table as most people think) and do your processing there. You clearly don't want to couple a model layer object with the shell - IMO.